# How can I change the position of a radio button to the other side of the text?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress-wpf

I want to change the radio button from the left of the text to the right of the text

[image: screenshot]

I currently have it as a `ListBoxEdit` with a radio button style

```
 <dxe:ListBoxEdit Name="xrbSplitFreight" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" FontWeight="Bold"  Grid.Column="8" Height="143" VerticalAlignment="center"  Width="218" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ShowBorder="False" Margin="0,0,0,7">
     <dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
         <dxe:RadioListBoxEditStyleSettings  />
     </dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
 </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
```

and I'm populating the `ListBoxEdit` with

```
 private void InitSources()
 {
     List<String> source = new List<String>();
     source.Add("Split Freight");
     source.Add("Print Comment");
     source.Add("Do Not Split Freight");          

     xrbSplitFreight.ItemsSource = source;
 }
```

I have tried looking through all the properties but I can't find anything that will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the property `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` for your `Radio Button` to Make it reverse.

```
<RadioButton Content="Hello" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
```

Comment: I do this like this, too, but be aware of mirrored images, if they are part of the `RadioButton`'s content. In this case I also set `Image.RenderTransform` to a `<ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>`. You might also need to do corrections on horizontal translation (`CenterX`).